# how to remove app icon in action bar of api 16 and above

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to remove app icon in action bar.

this is my code

> ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
>
> actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

but it not remove.

Comment: Use a custom view for your `ActionBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the App icon from actionbar in only an activity, try this

```
getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

If You want to hide app icon in Full Application Use

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

and

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: thank you, ok with "getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));"